# How to get all bugs I fixed?

Tags: bugzilla

This is probably obvious to any seasoned bugzilla user, but using the UI, how do I see all the bugs I have fixed?

I have looked in the search window, and there are lots of variables i can select from but nothing like resolved_by or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there's at least three things original poster might want to search for:

- All bugs RESOLVED by OP *as the resolving user.*
- All bugs RESOLVED by anyone while OP was the Assignee.
- All bugs presently RESOLVED/VERIFIED/CLOSED (by anyone) on which OP is *presently* the Assignee.

Bugzilla appears to not have a "resolved by" or "resolver" Custom Search term, but in 4.0.7 and hopefully the latest, 5.0.3, you *can* express the following in "Advanced | Custom Search":

- "Status" "changed by" "your_user_name" along with other boolean entries to limit it to currently RESOLVED/VERIFIED/CLOSED bugs and so on. That seems preferable to the accepted answer submitted by Fernando Oliveira, because it will only return bugs where OP was actually the user who changed the status.

Comment: i agree, please will you add an example search ?

Answer (score 1):

Click on "Simple Search", then select "Closed" status and click on "Search"

Comment: No, it shows all bugs closed by anyone. If you want a more sophisticated search only closed by you, then I recommend you to try "Advanced Search".  Select all products and categories you want to look into. Select the status and resolution that you want, then scroll down a little bit until "Search By People". Enter with your email and select all options (reporter, responsible, cc, etc..), then click on search.